# angular 2 innerHTMLchange event binding?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to do something like:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content" (innerHTMLchange)="contentInit()"></div>
```

As my code sits, I have a variable `content` that gets updated from a service that gets a string from my express server. The content variable is set and the innerHTML is updated when the site loads. Now I have a javascript lib that needs to do calls on the added string to the innerHTML. The problem I currently have is that the `contentInit()` is called before the HTML is updated.

```
constructor(private service: StringService) {
    this.service.getString().subscribe((string) => {
        this.content = string;
        this.contentInit(); // called before innerHTML changes
    });
}

contentInit: void {
    var innerHTMLDiv = document.getElementById("innerHTML-div");
    //do stuff
}
```

If the template can call the `contentInit()` when the innerHTML changes this should solve my problem as the innerHTML will be initiated and it can connect to the elements.

Comment: A bit hacky, but have you considered wrapping `this.contentInit();` in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: What causes the `innerHTMLchange` event to fire?

Comment: That's what I would like to know. If it is possible to have the function called when the `[innerhtml]` changes, when `this.content` is updated. @Günter

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke change detection explicitly instead of waiting for Angular to run the next cycle:

```
constructor(private service: StringService, cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.service.getString().subscribe((string) => {
        this.content = string;
        cdRef.detectChanges(); // after that the DOM is updated
        this.contentInit(); // called before innerHTML changes
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be too late to replay, but hope help someone , or get better idea.

If you want to apply some script to the updated innerHtml, you may call `setTimeout(() => contentInit(), 0)` to load the js once after the tick where angular finished the html render

```
this.service.getString().subscribe((string) => {
    this.content = string;
    setTimeout(() => contentInit(), 0)
});
```

`innerHtml` will be rendered through sync process after `this.content = string;`
and contentInit() will do its work in next tick.

The straight forward idea is to use [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) .
you need to put

```
import { AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

  private js_loaded = false;

  constructor(private service: StringService, cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.service.getString().subscribe((string) => {
        this.js_loaded = false;
        this.content = string;
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (!this.loaded && document.getElementById("innerHTML-div")) {
      this.js_loaded = true;
      this.contentInit();
    }
  }
}
```

`document.getElementById("innerHTML-div")` is testing the HTML is rendered already, you can use any selector in your content.

If you want to trigger the js in HTML, you may try to put a hidden tag 
`<div *ngIf="content">{{contentInit()}}</div>`
or `<div *ngIf="content"><div *ngIf="contentInit()"></div></div>`
But this way is not elegant, `contentInit()`  will be loaded many times, whenever content updated. This also need a if block to test wether content is changed when you change to another page.